# Ubuntu 18.04 do-release-upgrade fails screen \0\0 no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 but do-release-upgrade is failing to create an additional screen and exits to root prompt. Exiting from root prompt shows 'screen: \0\0: No such file or directory.'  Does anyone know how to resolve or workaround? Greatly appreciated.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                                                                      
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,338 kB]                                                                                                                                               
Fetched 1,340 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                              
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'
root@st1 Sun Apr 09 16:56:/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-os_4px5i# 
logout
screen: \0\0: No such file or directory
```

The following is from the dist-upgrade main.log

```
2023-04-09 16:58:27,233 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.bionic']'
2023-04-09 16:58:27,234 INFO uname information: 'Linux st1 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64'
2023-04-09 16:58:27,822 INFO apt version: '1.6.14'
2023-04-09 16:58:27,822 INFO python version: '3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]'
2023-04-09 16:58:27,828 INFO release-upgrader version '20.04.40' started
2023-04-09 16:58:27,844 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2023-04-09 16:58:30,917 DEBUG screen returned: ''
2023-04-09 16:58:30,917 INFO re-exec inside screen: '['screen', '-e', '\\0\\0', '-c', 'screenrc', '-S', 'ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window', '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-c36px3u_/focal', '--mode=server', '--frontend=DistUpgradeViewText']'
```